# power off during long sql transaction

Tags: sql, transactions, interrupt

Does anyone know what will happen if microsoft sql server's power is switched off during a long sql transaction?   will the db rollback the unfinished transaction by itself?

Thanks

Comment: Why not to try on some virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

The actual data-commit will never be excecuted so there is no problem with inconsistent data. There will be a rollback instead of a commit which wil happen as soon as the server restarts.

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> After the redo phase has rolled forward all the log transactions, a
>   database typically contains changes made by transactions that are
>   uncommitted at the recovery point. This makes the rolled forward data
>   transactionally inconsistent. **The recovery process opens the
>   transaction log to identify uncommitted transactions. Uncommitted
>   transactions are undone by being rolled back, unless they hold locks
>   that prevent other transactions from viewing transactionally
>   inconsistent data.** This step, is called the undo (or roll back) phase.
>   If the data is already transactionally consistent at the start of the
>   recovery process, the undo phase is skipped. After the database is
>   transactionally consistent, recovery brings the database online. After
>   one or more backups have been restored, recovery typically includes
>   both the redo and undo phases. Every full and differential backup
>   contains enough transaction log records to allow for the data in that
>   backup to be recovered to a self-consistent state.